# Which is the best method(Way) to Process SQL SERVER Database table faster in code(C#)?

Tags: c#, data-structures, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I have over 100k records in my SQL Server table. I want to take those records into the code(C#) and process that records. I have tried with Dataset and DataTable but taking each row from DataTable and process is taking so much time. Which is the best way to process faster? I got a suggestion from others that Data Structures would be the best way.

Comment: Can you please add the sample code that you've tried to implement? Having something to build off of will help any potential answerers.

Comment: Showing some code would help.  Not sure what kind of work you're doing on the data... which is kinda key.  Do you have plans to do any of this processing in parallel using C#?  More recent versions of SQL DBs, including SQL are able to apply multiple workers on a per query basis. Rolling your own version is gonna be some work...

Comment: There are many ways that this could be done, but without knowing what we are dealing with it is hard to guide you. Code, schema, sample data, actual processing, and disposition of the processed data would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I usually use sqlcmd.exe which is an archiving tool that comes with SQL Server.  It can generate a csv file output which you can read into you c# application.  It is the quickest way to run any query.  In c# I usually set up a bat cmd and then launch as a process.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Comment: @James Z Thank you